# Black spots while ripening store brought mangoes by paper

Tags: fruit, ripe, mango

I live in Delhi where most retail mangoes are ripened using carbide. Therefore, certain stores sell unripe mangoes which are supposed to be ripened before eating. One method that is popular is wrapping individual mangoes in newspapers.

However, most of them develop black spots before ripening which leads to degradation of pulp in many areas in the mango and basically does not allow one to keep it till it ripens completely. There's also some wrinkling happening. What is the reason for this and how does one fix this issue? Hay is not available here so ripening them in boxes is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely just a sign of ripening and fine to eat: [MANGO DEFECT GUIDE](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://australian-mangoes.squarespace.com/s/AMIA-Mango-Quality-DEFECT-GUIDE-2016.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi4gO3iiNfxAhVSUK0KHb5EA7UQFjAIegQIIRAC&usg=AOvVaw3EHpopr3IwPiRsIiqpmuR3)

Hay would be nice, but the paper should be keeping the mangoes from dampness causing rot.

An ugly mango can be delicious while an unblemished one tart or bland.